# Should I deactivate current conda env before creating a new one?

Tags: python, conda

Does it make any difference in creating a new conda environment from which conda environment? I mean, should I create all of my environments from the `base` environment?

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not necessary and it makes no difference *under normal circumstances*.<sup>**1**</sup> The `conda` commands are wired in such a way that the entrypoint robustly points back to the **base** environment.

---

<sub>**[1]**: One abnormal circumstance in particular can cause problems: when a user installs the `conda` package in environments other than **base**. This can result in nesting environment directories and just general mess. Don't install `conda` (or `mamba`) in anywhere other than **base**.</sub>